# Why does std::allocator_traits not have function `address`

Tags: c++, c++11, allocator

`std::allocator_traits` has `allocate`, `deallocate`, `construct`, `destroy`, and `max_size`, but not `address`.

- Why not?
- If it is safe to always use `std::addressof`, why does `std::allocator` support `address`?

Comment: `std::addressof` is C++11. `std::allocator`'s `address` is C++03 and remains for compatibility.

Comment: The latter question doesn't make much sense; could you please clarify what it is that you are asking about?

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp: My assumption was that `custom_allocator<T>::address` exists to support an allocator where the storage is not actually backed by memory, which is why `pointer` exists instead of just using `value_type *`. If this is not true, `std::allocator::address` seems pointless.

Comment: @David: Nope. It's there to support "fancy pointers" from the 16 bit era when you had "near" and "far" pointers. You would need to know if it was going to be `value_type *` or `value_type FAR *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::allocator::address` has been part of `std::allocator` since the type has existed in the standard, but it was deprecated in C++17 and removed in C++20. `allocator_traits` was added to C++11 by [N2982: "Allocators post Removal of C++ Concepts (Rev 1)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2982.pdf). That paper removed `address` from the allocator requirements and states:

> The functionality of `address` is now provided by the `pointer_to` function in `pointer_traits`.